# Delete timers alarm before it fire callback nodemcu

Tags: timer, nodemcu

I have for example this code on my function on my nodemcu:

```
mytimer = tmr.create()
mytimer:register(5000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function() digitalWrite(16, HIGH) end)
```

But, before 5 seconds, I want delete this timer with another function, because if I want (before 5 seconds) launch a function like:

```
digitalWrite(16, LOW)
```

If I don't delete timers, it toggle state of led.
So, how can I delete certain timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either call `mytimer:stop()` or `mytimer:unregister()` depending on whether you want to restart it later on or not.

**UPDATE:** Just showing this picture to proof the working example:
[image: working example]

**Hint:** make sure the `mytimer` variable is accessible from within the other function.

Please also have a look at the [timer documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/tmr) before posting a question.

Comment: I have read: tmr.ALARM_SINGLE a one-shot alarm (and no need to call tmr.unregister())  and Stops a running timer, but does not unregister it. so It seems that once I have registered my timer it will fire however the event, even I unregister immediately

Comment: @LorenzoBerti in my understanding you don't *need* to call `tmr.unregister()` but you *could* do it, in order to avoid that the callback is fired. I will try to verify this after noon.

Comment: @LorenzoBerti please see the working example withing the updated answer. In order to help you figuring out what's going wrong in your case, please post a reproducible minimum example.